# How handle Push Notification in two mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

In My Application have Two Mode

```
1. Driver Mode
2. Passenger Mode
```

2) Passenger can send request to driver

```
-Driver has two option 1)Accept 2)cancel

if driver accepts invitation then passenger screen shows driver contact list.

if driver cancels invitation then passenger shows Find New Driver Screen.
```

Comment: if driver accept the invitation means then send api request ,from back end they have to send pushnotification using your pem file. then manage with that receiving notification.

Comment: yes, invitation means Send Api Request

Comment: yes send Api Request @kalpesh

Comment: Maintain one "key" named like "type" in notification payload(data). And differentiate the notification based on that key.

Answer (score 2):

While user touch the notification your response will receive here ,this method is placed in AppDelegate.m file.

```
  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
         NSLog(@"this is user info%@",userInfo);
         //here you can handle those things. 
    }
```